# How do I display a property from a child element in a ListBox bound with ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I can't figure this out, consider the following code:

```
 <ListBox Width="200" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentArticle.ArticleCategories}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Category.Name}">
  </ListBox>
```

`ArticleCategories` is a table in my database that contains 2 foreign keys, 1 to `Article` and 1 to `Categories`, so `ArticleCategories` is a list that contains `Articles` and `Categories`.

I want to show which **categories** the current article(`CurrentArticle`) have in this listbox and I can't figure out how to do so. I want to show `Category.Name` for each `Category` in the `ListBox`.

Right now, the listbox is showing "**Data.ArticleCategory**" because it dont know how to display it.

I have tried `DisplayMemberPath="Category.Name"` without success.

Do I need to use some sort of Data Template, if so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DisplayMemberPath is not a field where you add a binding, its just the name of your Property on the given Item. `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` should be enough.

Comment: I have tried that, didnt work, still showing Data.ArticleCategory.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is, that this only works for direct Properties, but you want a property from another object you want to access. While this works for binding, i don't think this works for DisplayMemberPath. What you should do now is create an ItemTemplate, add a TextBlock and the text property is your initial binding you tried in DisplayMemberPath. Because DisplayMemberPath is just a shortcut and in my experience it is only valuable in 20% of the use cases.

Comment: Adding itemtemplate and having 
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category.Name}"></TextBlock> worked!
I dont know why but as u said, sometimes it dont work with only DisplayMemberPath.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a binding:

```
DisplayMemberPath="Category.Name"
```

EDIT: since you're binding `ItemsSource` to `CurrentArticle.ArticleCategories`, I assume that the items of your ListBox are objects of type `Category`? in that case the path should be just "Name", not "Category.Name".

Comment: I have tried that, didnt work, still showing Data.ArticleCategory

Comment: @Thomas, `ArticleCategories` consist of an `ArticleCategory`-object that is a relational entity. So there is an `Article` property and a `Category` property on each `ArticleCategory`. I think that is what he tried to explain after the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ListBox.ItemTemplate with a datatemplate that looks the way you like:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx